# to identify emoji character with in string and revesring all

Tags: objective-c

I was getting the `NSString` from `UIWebView` which contain iPhone emoji and reversing text excluding emoji. I need to display reverse of `NSString` again in `UIWebView` but couldn't get the reversed string with emoji. I am not identifying the emoji character in string. I have xcode 4.5 with iOS 6.0. here is my code:

```
 - (NSString *) createReverseStringFromString:(NSString *)inputString {
  if (inputString.length <= 0)
    return inputString;

 NSMutableString *mutableReverseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] 
 initWithCapacity:inputString.length];
 Thfor (NSInteger i = inputString.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {

    NSString *characterString = [inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    [mutableReverseString appendString:characterString];

    NSLog(@"mutableReverseString..%@",mutableReverseString);
 }

 NSString *outputString = [mutableReverseString copy];
 [mutableReverseString release];
return [outputString autorelease];
 }
```

Comment: what do u mean by reversing emoji ?

Comment: I want to reverse all chracters not emoji

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that many emoji characters are internally stored as a "surrogate pair" of two characters.

For example, "THUMBS UP SIGN" is Unicode point U+1F44D, but if you store it in an `NSString` and use `substringWithRange` to get single characters, you will get two characters:

```
U+D83D, U+DC4D
```

which is the UTF-16 surrogate pair for U+1F44D.

Of course, if you reverse these two characters, the output is garbage.

The solution is to use `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex` to get sequences of characters which "belong together":

```
- (NSString *) createReverseStringFromString:(NSString *)inputString {
    if (inputString.length <= 0)
        return inputString;

    NSMutableString *mutableReverseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] 
                         initWithCapacity:inputString.length];

    NSInteger i = inputString.length;
    while (i > 0) {
        NSRange range = [inputString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:i-1];
        NSString *characterString = [inputString substringWithRange:range];
        [mutableReverseString appendString:characterString];
        i = range.location;
    }

    NSString *outputString = [mutableReverseString copy];
    return outputString;
}
```

This function correctly reverses strings containing emoji characters.

(*Note:* I have omitted all `release`, `autorelease` calls because I always compile with ARC. You have to add that again where appropriate.)

Comment: Great explanation! It helps me a lot! The wiki link about UTF-16 and surrogate pair: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: great explanation! Note that if you use emoji chars like flags, this will not work because flags are actually four characters.

Comment: @drakos: That is interesting! I had not seen these "regional indicator symbols" and their special treatment as flags before. I would have assumed that rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex: takes care of that, but it doesn't.

Comment: @drakos: On the other hand,  is two valid Unicode characters:  and , so it might be difficult to decide whether they should stick together or not. - Anyway, thanks for the feedback. I learned something new today!

Comment: How could I remove the emoji chars from a string ?
[emojiCharSet addCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0xE000, 0xE537 - 0xE000)];

Comment: @Jango: Apple does not this "legacy encoding" for Emojis. For example,  is U+1F600. And what about other symbols like  = U+1F688, should they be removed as well? - In any case, I would suggest that you post a new question where you describe exactly what characters should be removed.